# Appending Data to an Interface Pointing to a Defined Struct using 'reflect'

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, reflection, append

I am trying to create a function where it gets all the documents from a Mongo Collection and queries them to declared structs. To achieve this I set the parameters for the function of type interface so it can work with two structs. Here is my code:

In package entities:

```
type Project struct {
    Title string
    Position string
    ....
}

type Projects struct {
    Projects []Project
}
```

In the current package:

```
var docs entities.Projects
var doc entities.Project

//doc represents a document from Mongo Collection 
//docs represents an array of documents, each element is a document
//collection has type *mongo.Collection and points to the desired collection on MongoDB.
createQuery(&doc, &docs, collection)

func createQuery(doc interface{}, docs interface{}, c *mongo.Collection) {
    documents := reflect.ValueOf(docs).Elem()
    document := reflect.ValueOf(doc)

    cur, err := c.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{{}})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
        err = cur.Decode(document.Interface())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        //Error is thrown here
        documents.Set(reflect.Append(documents, document))
        fmt.Println(doc)
    }
    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("oh shit this is the error %s \n", err)
    }
    cur.Close(context.Background())

    fmt.Printf("documents: %+v\n", documents.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("document: %+v\n", document.CanSet())
}


---ERROR OUTPUT---
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Append on struct Value
```

I was able to set data to doc using the document variable, although when doing document.CanSet() is false (so it may not even work). Where the program breaks is when I try to append the document to the documents interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question passes the struct `docs` to a function that expects a slice. Pass the address of the slice field in `docs` instead of `docs` itself.

The `createQuery` function can determine the slice element type from the slice itself. There's no need to pass in an example value.

```
var docs entities.Projects
createQuery(&docs.Projects, collection)
for _, doc := range docs.Projects {
   fmt.Println(doc.Title)
}
```

The call to `cur.Decode` requires a pointer to an uninitialized value. Use reflect.New to create that value.

```
func createQuery(docs interface{}, c *mongo.Collection) {
    docsv := reflect.ValueOf(docs).Elem()
    doct := docsv.Type().Elem()

    cur, err := c.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{{}})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
        docpv := reflect.New(doct)
        err = cur.Decode(docpv.Interface())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        docsv.Set(reflect.Append(docsv, docpv.Elem()))
    }
    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    cur.Close(context.Background())
}
```

As an aside, the `entities.Projects` struct type is not needed if that struct type will only ever have one field.  Use `[]Project` instead:

```
var docs []entities.Project
createQuery(&docs, collection)
for _, doc := range docs {
   fmt.Println(doc.Title)
}
```

Comment: The call to `createQuery(&docs.Projects, collection)` decodes documents to an `entities.Project` value and appends those values to the slice `docs.Projects`.  The application can iterate through the documents and access fields like so: `for _, doc := range docs.Projects {
   fmt.Println(doc.Title)
}
`

Comment: it decodes the documents to an entities.Project value through Projects because []Project? sorry for lack of knowledge still kind of getting used to Go! Thanks for the massive amounts of help!!!

Comment: The function is passed a pointer to a `[]entities.Project`. The function decodes to values values of that slice element type.  The fact that the slice is a field in `entities.Projects` has no relevance to the function.

Comment: it throws this error ```panic: reflect: Elem of invalid type``` at ```documentType := documentsVal.Type().Elem()``` also when i do docsv.String() it points to entities.Projects

Comment: so it throws no error and it works if i do []entities.Project.

Comment: It looks like you are passing the address of `entities.Projects`  to the function. Pass the address of the Project's Projects field as shown in the answer: `var docs entities.Projects; createQuery(&docs.Projects, collection)`.

Comment: Yup, that's the answer! I was stuck on this problem for so long that i had a case of tunnel vision thanks for the help!